# Host-wide consequences of setting SELinux z/Z option on container bind mounts

Tags: docker, selinux, podman, container

When running podman containers with volume mounts, it is often necessary to add the `:z` (or `:Z`) parameter to the mount path. It is due to SELinux and its type enforcement. What the parameter does is it changes the type of the mounted files. I think that it is actually quite dangerous operation and it could potentially cause some issues if we mount some files that need some other SELinux type applied.
Let's consider an example of an apache httpd server. As far as I know, httpd can only serve files from directiories that are marked with an appropriate label (like `httpd_file_t` or whatever, doesn't matter). What will happen if I start a podman container and mount the httpd's `www` directory to it (with `:z`)? The context would get changed to `container_file_t` type, and I believe the server would stop working (it would lose access to the files in `www`).

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. From the Docker manual (essentially the same as with podman):

```
Configure the selinux label

If you use selinux you can add the z or Z options to modify the selinux label of the host file or directory being mounted into the container. This affects the file or directory on the host machine itself and can have consequences outside of the scope of Docker.

    The z option indicates that the bind mount content is shared among multiple containers.
    The Z option indicates that the bind mount content is private and unshared.

Use extreme caution with these options. Bind-mounting a system directory such as /home or /usr with the Z option renders your host machine inoperable and you may need to relabel the host machine files by hand.
```

That means that if you bind mount a certain host directory into Docker, the SELinux context label will be changed to make sure that particular directory is only accessible from that particular container (`:Z`) or from all containers (`:z`).

Because these actions are performed on the host filesystem itself, they will have consequences *outside the scope of the container virtualization*. Your example is a good one: when bind mounting a host webroot, the standard `httpd_sys_(rw_)content_t` will be replaced. Apache on the host will then refuse to serve that webroot.

Fortunately, this is easily overcome using a custom policy module.

Use `:z` or `:Z` and start Docker/podman. Make sure it works. Now set SELinux to permissive using `setenforce 0`. Then start up Apache. It will work (because of SELinux being permissive), but AVC denials will be logged in the audit log.

```bash
# use the output of ausearch to create a policy that allows this. This is the dry-run version
ausearch -m avc -ts recent | audit2allow -a
# If you're satisfied that this is indeed a module you want to add to the SELinux system,
# pick a policyname (use a custom prefix like mnj-) and run
ausearch -m avc -ts recent | audit2allow -a -M mnj-[policyname]
```

This creates a policy module file in `/etc/selinux/targeted/modules/active/modules`.

To install and activate this module, run:

`semodule -i mnj-[policyname].pp`

Now re-enable SELinux: `setenforce 1`. Apache will now be able to serve the webroot again.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicion. And thanks for providing some solution. I think I will most often use `--security-opt label=disable` when having issues. It's probably not very safe. However, I believe that it will cause harm if and only if the process within container manages to break out of the "sandbox". That would require some flaw in podman itself to be discovered and used I think.